# No muestra los articulos relacionados con la categoria. Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

Tengo un problema con mostrar los articulos que ya he creado y que tengo en la base de datos pero que no puedo mostrar en la vista mediante category_id que es con lo que está relacionado el articulo a la categoria.

Modelo Category

```
class Category extends Model{

    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];


    //Relacion uno a muchos
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class); 
    }
    public function articles(){
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class); 
    }
}
```

Modelo article

```
class Article extends Model{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    
    //Relacion uno a muchos inversa
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(category::class);
    }
}
```

Ruta

```
Route::get('category/{category}',[ProductController::class, 'category'])->name('product.category');
```

Controlador

```
public function category(Category $category){
        $products = Product::where('category_id', $category->id)
            ->where('status', 2)
            ->latest('id')
            ->paginate(16);
        $articles = Article::where('category_id', $category->id)
            ->latest('id');
        return view('pages.products.category', compact('products', 'category', 'articles'));
    }
```

Vista hago los foreach de article y products

```
 @foreach ($articles as $article)
            <div>
                <h1>{{$article->name}}</h1>
                
                <figure>
                    <img src="{{Storage::url($article->image->url)}}">
                </figure>
            </div>
        @endforeach

        <div>     
            @foreach ($products as $product)
              <img src="{{Storage::url($product->image->url)}}">   
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

Comment: He añadido los foreach que muestro en la vista, el de products si me va perfectamente pero el otro no

Comment: Gracias, ahora me va casi perfecto, consigo mostrar todo lo que subi a la DB excepto las imagenes :( aparece como dañadas

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto, hice uso del método "get()" para hacer la consulta a la tabla. El controlador quedó de la siguiente forma:

```
public function category(Category $category){
        $products = Product::where('category_id', $category->id)
            ->where('status', 2)
            ->latest('id')
            ->paginate(16);
        $articles = Article::where('category_id', $category->id)
            ->latest('id')->get; 
        return view('pages.products.category', compact('products', 'category', 'articles'));
    }
```